# Are there any jump-capable fighters in the books that don't have an astromech?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny

After finding only fighters that have astromechs that are jump-capable in the books I have, I'm wondering: Are there any fighters in expansions or supplements that are jump capable and *don't* have an astromech?

(I'm talking here about an innate jump capability, not one with acceleration rings).

Or is it that, for fighter-sized ships, an astromech is a must-have if they are to be jump capable in the game setting?

Comment: Is this a matter of curiosity about a setting detail or are you trying to do something that needs a jump-capable fighter without an astromech?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie My groups gms decided to not give out a freighter as group resource but instead starfighters. And that made me wonder if they in essence brought upon themselves 5 astromechs or not^^. So in essence curiousity about setting details according to the rpg (in the novels I know a few examples like the star killer from legends).

Comment: Since just about everything exists in the EU (TIE Advanced X1 off the top of my head), and based on your comment, I've edited your question to clarify that you're looking for sources specific to this game. If that's not what you meant, please feel free to revert and/or make your own edit.

Comment: @SirTechSpec yepp I'm looking for things directly in the books (which is also why I put it into the rpg stackexchange as oppposed to scifi stackexchange)

Answer (score 2):

There are several starfighters in various supplements that have  navicomputers instead of astromechs. Too numerous to list, but there is an [amazingly through repository](http://swrpg.viluppo.net/transportation/starships/) that has pretty much everything categorized for you. Just find the type of ship you want, and see what book it comes from!

In addition to ships with on-board navicomputers, you can always install an astrogation droid brain attachment—found on page 62 of *Fly Casual*.